# How to select every second row with a certain date in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, vector, character

I have a data set containing Trump's daily schedules as a character vector, along with a date vector. However, some days have multiple schedules.

I want to concatenate all the schedules for each individual date into one chr schedule for each date. How can I do this?

Example with tiny sample data set:

```
chr <- c("please", "help", "me", "god")
date <- c("2018-06-26, "2018-06-26", "2018-06-27", "2018-06-28)
my_current_df <- data.frame(chr,date)

intended_vector <- c("please help", "me", "god")
intended_df <- data.frame(intended_vector,date)
```

EDIT: Problem solved! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `aggregate` for a base R option:

```
chr <- c("please", "help", "me", "god")
date <- c("2018-06-26", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-27", "2018-06-28")
df <- data.frame(chr, date)

aggregate(data=df, chr~date, FUN = function(t) paste(t))

        date          chr
1 2018-06-26 please, help
2 2018-06-27           me
3 2018-06-28          god
```

### Demo

Comment: Sorry, my example was poorly worded. What I currently have is "my_current_df". What i'm trying to get is "intended_df".

Comment: @AndrewAcomb Your update doesn't really change my answer.  Visit the demo link in my answer to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `dplyr`:

```
chr <- c("please", "help", "me", "god") 
date <- c("2018-06-26", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-27", "2018-06-28")
df <- data.frame(chr, date)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(chr = trimws(paste0(chr, " ", collapse = '')))
```

This returns your desired output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date       chr        
  <fct>      <chr>      
1 2018-06-26 please help
2 2018-06-27 me         
3 2018-06-28 god
```

Comment: this created a chr vector with only one element "pleasehelpmegod"

Comment: @AndrewAcomb: See my edit. Now it returns exactly what you are searching for.